# Why is this specific question not being closed/deleted even after being flagged?

Tags: discussion

## Question on SO link:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/43352507/5779732

## Contents of question:

> Working on a project where I need to perform post processing on CT
>   scan images that are stored in DICOM (.dcm) files. I need to get at
>   and modify the underlying pixels for a given image. I have looked into
>   java DICOM frameworks such as PixelMed and dcm4che but have not found
>   anything that allows me to access and modify pixel values (e,g,
>   convert raw pixel values hounsfield units and other transforms.)
>
> A java library recommendation and code snippet will be greatly
>   appreciated.

## My comment:

> 1) This is too broad until you finalize ONE toolkit. 2) This is
>   off-topic because you are asking us to find a library for you.

When I first read this question, I found two issues with it.

1. It is too broad until OP finalize ONE toolkit.
2. It is off-topic because OP is asking us to find/recommend a library/code for him.

I left a comment for OP and flagged the question for deletion saying it's off-topic. After a few days, OP posted a comment that indicates that he is not interested in editing the question to make it on-topic.

> boo on you for that comment.

I flagged the comment for moderator attention.

Nothing has happened so far. Why has this question not yet been deleted? Is there anything wrong in what I am doing?

Comment: Only thing you seem to be missing is some patience... There are currently over 700 flags waiting for moderator attention, your being one of these. Moderators do not have a "flag handling" SLA. The question isn't deleted because it isn't closed - delete votes can only be cast on closed questions - both of these (close and delete votes) are things that do not require moderators - the community will take care of them.

Comment: Well, you can't see it because you do not have enough rep but it already has 4 close votes on it.

Comment: There is a real, solvable problem underneath though. The question itself can be salvaged and could be very useful for future visitors. I'm going to see if I can edit it into shape.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: That was my first impression. But how can I (or you or anyone else) edit it to make it on-topic until OP selects **ONE** toolkit? That is why my comment there.

Comment: @A_J That's assuming the question should be "how do I do this with toolkit X". It doesn't have to be. In fact, trying to do this specifically "with toolkit X" can make it an X/Y problem. The underlying question is about manipulating .dcm files. Whatever toolkit is used for this - if any - is secondary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was already said by @Oded in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348166/why-this-specific-question-is-not-being-closed-deleted-even-after-flagging#comment467122_348166), it just takes a little patience. The Close Votes queue has close to 10.000 questions, this was only one of them.

About the question itself - it ends with a tool request. I've edited that out, because as you've correctly told the asker, tool requests are textbook off-topic.

The question seems broad, but when you look closer, it simply asks how to get at individual pixel values in a .dcm image, using Java. This is a real issue, that can be objectively answered.
The asker also told us what they'd tried - two different libraries that did not offer functionality for this.

You did right to point out what was wrong with the question; the asker's response was not professional, and you rightfully flagged it. That said, I've see far worse responses. At least they didn't compare us to murderous dictators... (did I sound jaded now?)

There is some value in that question, and a DICOM expert could probably provide the asker and future visitors with some valuable insights. It is one of those [grains of sand that may produce a pearl](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). For that reason, I have edited it and voted to reopen.